# Refresh combox of a form after insert in database done in another form c#

Tags: c#

I have a form that use it to insert data (Form2), that data is shown in a combobox that exists in another form (form1), I want to refresh that combobox after inserting in form2

Here is my code (form1)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string libelle = textBox1.Text;
    string cause = textBox2.Text;
    string interval = textBox3.Text +'-'+ textBox4.Text;

    d.open();
    int c =  d.InsertPanne(libelle, cause, interval);

    if (c == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Panne ajoutée avec succès");

        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();
        textBox4.Clear();

        Form1 f = new Form1();
        f.Refresh();
    }

    d.close();
}
```

Form1 code :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    add_panne p = new add_panne();
    DAO d = new DAO();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<panne> liste1 = d.getPannes();

        comboBox3.DataSource = new BindingSource(liste1,null);
        comboBox3.DisplayMember = "nompan";
        comboBox3.ValueMember = "numpan";

        comboBox3.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a BindingList in your Data layer then it should just work automatically.

I have attached an sample VS project which demonstrates what I believe you are wanting to do.

[WindowsFormsComboRefresh VS project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxOZb1Lhz7xHYWxnS2d3NWV6cE0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I am using this comboBox3.DataSource = new BindingSource(liste1,null); how I'm gonna do what you did please

Comment: how can I use class.instance on binding Source

Comment: mBindingSrc = new BindingSource(mData.MyData, "Name");
comboBox1.DataSource = mBindingSrc.DataSource;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";

I changed MyData to be a BindingList<Food> rather than string.

Here is the food class
public class Food
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 0):

**Crete new function e.g. UpdateFormsControl**

```
private void UpdateFormsControls()
{
 List<panne> liste1 = d.getPannes();

    comboBox3.DataSource = null;
    comboBox3.DataSource = liste1 ;
    comboBox3.DisplayMember = "nompan";
    comboBox3.ValueMember = "numpan";

    comboBox3.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    textBox1.Clear();
                    textBox2.Clear();
                    textBox3.Clear();
                    textBox4.Clear();

}
```

Just Call this function to Refresh Items of Combo Box...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string libelle = textBox1.Text;
                string cause = textBox2.Text;
                string interval = textBox3.Text +'-'+ textBox4.Text;

                d.open();
              int c =  d.InsertPanne(libelle, cause, interval);
                if (c == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Panne ajoutée avec succès");

   //Call Update function to update values
UpdateFormsControls();
                    Form1 f = new Form1();
                    f.Refresh();


                }

                d.close();

            }
```